# Project won't run in eclipse after building. It does not do anything

Tags: android

It does not do anything. sometimes I have to keep hitting the "Run" option in the menu several times before it actually runs. Same thing goes for building the project.  what is going on here?

thanks.

Comment: While this comment may be strange, where do you "Run" the project? Based on my experience, you cannot run the project if the active window is XML resource.

Comment: Yikes my active window was the XML resource. That explains it. It works now. Thanks.